# MVC3 musicstore tutorial: can't login with administrator account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

I am currently following the MVC Musicstore tutorial from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7 and got stuck on the part with the Authorization.

To get the basics covered: I am using VS Web Developer 2012 and created a mvc4 application. 
The "DefaultConnection" got replaced by "MusicStoreConnection". To reflect this in the code in InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs I changed a lin to:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MusicStoreConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Now, if a run the application I can create a user and log in with the credentials. However: if a run the asp.net configuration and create a user there, assign him to the administrator role and try to login it fails.

What do I have to do in order to get the asp.net conf created user work in my application, so I can follow the tutorial?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the MusicStore tutorial, which was written using MVC3 and used original ASP.NET Membership provider introduced in 2005. MVC4 Internet Template uses SimpleMembership and is no longer compatible with the WSAT (ASP.NET configuration).

Here you can find more information about membership in MVC4 - [more info](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve this by following the instruction below:
source: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/discussions/219225

> **kate0824** Jul 28, 2010 at 6:18 PM Edited Jul 28, 2010 at 6:20 PM I have checking this problem today and finally find that when you are
>   using the Asp.net configuration tool, you are actually working with
>   Asp.net Membership function.
>
> 1. Being sure that don't import the file named ASPNETDB.MEF in the source code that the MvcMusic Team provid(It contains their user
>      information).
> 2. Click on the tool(another way:Project->Asp.net Configuration),and create a user on the site.
>
> 3.Add an existing item named ASPNETDB.MEF into App_Data folder from your project's location.
>
> 1. click on the "Refresh" button upon the SolutionExplorer. After that,your Authorization configuration will function.Checking the
>      web.config file,you can find membership tag,check it